How does a non-native speaker deal with undefined words?
Following on the discussion of weiterverlaufen, I noticed this sentence in the same text:

Das Gelände fiel hier steil zu dem grün überwucherten Sumpfgebiet hin ab, das Toomey die Barrens genannt hatte.

I note that, DWDS and Duden define abfallen, and Duden defines hinabfallen, but what is a non-native speaker to make of "hin abfallen", which does not appear to be specifically referenced in either? Particularly, since in the discussion of weiterverlaufen it was pointed out that the meaning may differ depending upon whether or not the prefix is separated from the main verb or not. And why is this not "fiel... hinab."? When Schönlast says in the weiterverlaufen discussion, "Does the sentence containing the word have a meaning that is understood by the majority of German native speakers?", I am perplexed, because what provides assurance that these "understandings" correspond to each other?
To me it appears that, when a German speaker wishes to use a separable verb like hinabfallen, he may arbitrarily choose to separate it or not, in any way it may be separated, and whatever he means by it will be somehow understood. I would like to know the source of this magic.

The question title and the actual question aren't the same since the title is about compound words in general and the question is about how separable verbs work. Plus the example makes some incorrect assumptions. So to me it's unclear what's being asked and how to answer it. Maybe it would help to include more examples to give a better idea of what you want to know.

Also, though this is off-topic, I don't know about German speaking countries but where I'm from it's usually considered impolite to refer to someone by just their last name, especially when it's not spelled correctly. When in doubt, I would just copy and paste the entire username.

Point taken. My sincere apologies to Herr Schönlast.

And please spell his name correctly.

@RDBury I wouldn't say  it is impolite. In newpapers and news broadcast people are very frequently referred by  their last name. See e.g. here: "Scholz sagte weiter". But I agree to you that  in this forum one should use the entire username.

The verb »hinabfallen« was not used in that sentence. Here is how it would separate in a correct German sentence:

not separated (with a modal verb) in Präsens

Der Ball kann vom Tisch hinabfallen.
The ball can fall off the table.
(literal: The ball can fall off from the table.)


separated in Präteritum

Der Ball fiel vom Tisch hinab.
The ball fell off the table.
(literal: The ball fell off from the table.)




The verb in your sentence is just »abfallen« and »hin« is there as a normal adverb.
The fact that the adverb »hin« and the separable verb »abfallen« are used together in the same sentence is pure coincidence, and no more unusual than the coincidence of any other verb with any other adverb, as long as the resulting sentence makes some sense.

without specifying the destination of the tilted position

with modal verb (the separable verb is not separated), in Präsens.

Das Gelände kann abfallen.
The terrain can be sloping.


without modal verb (the separable verb is separated), in Präteritum.

Das Gelände fiel ab.
The terrain was sloping.




specifying the destination of the tilted position

with modal verb (the separable verb is not separated), in Präsens.

Das Gelände kann zum Sumpfgebiet hin abfallen.
The terrain can be sloping to the swamp.


without modal verb (the separable verb is separated), in Präteritum.

Das Gelände fiel zum Sumpfgebiet hin ab.
The terrain was sloping to the swamp.






Yes, I see that now. Not hinabfallen, but zu ... hin abfallen. Very clear and understood. Thank you.

In my experience German is much more likely to add directional adverbs than English, to the point where you almost can't move an inch without a "hin" or "her" or "rein" or "raus" being involved somehow. These adverbs can seem unnecessary and confusing to an English speaker; why add "hin" to "Das Gelände fiel zum Sumpfgebiet ab," when the sentence seems perfectly clear without it? My feeling is that motion without an explicitly stated direction seems vague and unsatisfying to German speakers, so it's just something you have to get used to if you're learning the language.

But I would like to point out a counterexample from DWDS:  "NN und etwa 90 m über dem Talgrund der Schwarzen Pockau, zu der er steil hinabfällt". This is not, " NN und etwa 90 m über dem Talgrund der Schwarzen Pockau, zu der hin er steil abfällt. "

@user44591: The relative clauses »..., zu der er steil hinabfällt.« (..., to which it falls down steeply) and »..., zu der hin er steil abfällt.« (..., towards which it falls down steeply) are two different clauses. Both are correct and have a very similar meaning, but not exactly the same meaning. Note, that also this is possible and correct: »..., zu der hin er steil hinabfällt« and even this is correct:  »..., zu der hinab er steil hinabfällt«. Similar coincidences of adverb and prefix of a separable verb exist in »Sandra geht mit Walter mit.« »Laura ...

... passt auf Lisa auf.« »Kurt schaut durch das Loch durch.« Sometimes you can replace a separable verb with another verb that has not that prefix (correct: schauen instead of durchschauen: »Kurt schaut durch das Loch«). But that is not always possible (wrong: passen instead of aufpassen: »Laura passt auf Lisa«). And sometimes it's possible, but chances the meaning: »Sandra geht mit Walter mit.« = Sandra and Walter walk together along the same path which is determined by Walter. But »Sandra geht mit Walter.« can also mean Sandra and Walter are a couple in love.

@HubertSchölnast If you can suggest a strategy for a non-German speaker to learn to understand the differences in meanings between the various possible uses of prefixes and verbs, such as you describe, that would be appreciated. I would be at a loss to understand the variation in meanings for those examples you have given, for instance.

@user44591 The counterexample seems to be taken from Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katzenstein_(Pobershau). I consider this as an error in this context. To me hinabfallen would mean that the rock formation would fall down to the river, which does not make sense. (It would be possible for a loose stone to fall down.) steil abfallen in this context means that the rock formation slopes down steeply towards the river. I think it must be "..., zu der hin er steil abfällt"

@user44591: Sorry, I can't suggest such a strategy. It's just a very difficult subject to learn because there are so many rules, all of which are also very vague. What helps is to use the language a lot (listen to German podcasts, watch German movies and videos, read German newspapers and blogs, talk to people who understand German).

You understood the rationale of the answers to the weiterverlaufen question wrong. Let's review it with weiterverkaufen as that one is established even in dictionaries. Compare:

Er kann dieses Produkt weiterverkaufen.

He can retail this product.
This is the verb weiterverkaufen, which means to sell what you bought, to sell on, to retail.

Er kann dieses Produkt weiter verkaufen.

He can continue selling this product.
This on the other hand is the verb verkaufen which means to sell plainly, combined with the adverb weiter which means further. This weiter / further means not that he sells it to another person (in the sense of weiterverkaufen) but that he can continue with selling it.
It's a difficulty in German word order that adverbs may end up right in front of verbs, same as prefixes. And because there's often prefixes that are made from adverbs, the only thing which tells the two apart is the extra space inbetween. In speech, people even rearrange the stress pattern of the sentence to point out that space and difference in meaning. Weiterverkaufen is stressed on wei, while weiter verkaufen is stressed on kau.
Some combinations mean the same with or without the space while others do not. This depends a lot on context. It's safe to assume that they don't.

Yes, I see the error of my ways now.
